# Release version not working. Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have been programming a Window Application, for Windows, and in Debug mode everything works but when I want switch to release mode the Window that opens in Debug does not open. If I try it without Visual Studio a Task is visible in Task manager but no window.

To be honest right now I can't understand anything I have in this code, I understood it 3 months ago but due to circumstances I have not worked with this in the last months and this is my first window application and my first application I release.

The following code should be everything that handles the creation of the Window.

```
This program creates a simple user interface (WinAPI) for entering the desired button cycles.
The entered button cycles are then sent to the button test device via a bound TCP / IP client.
As soon as the push button test device is finished with the switching cycles, it transmits the incorrect switching and the task switching to the TCP / IP client.
As soon as the data has been received by the TCP / IP client, it is written to a .csv file by a CSV writer.

*/

#include <Windows.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include "TCP-IP-Client.h"

HWND hWndEdit;
wchar_t buffer[1024];


LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 10) {
            GetWindowText(hWndEdit, buffer, 1024);
            int Input[1] = { _wtoi(buffer) };
            switch (TcpIpClient(Input)) {
            case 10:
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Can't start Winsock" , L"Benachrichtigung", MB_ICONERROR);
                break;
            case 11:
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Can't create socket", L"Benachrichtigung", MB_ICONERROR);
                break;
            case 12:
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Can't connect to server", L"Benachrichtigung", MB_ICONERROR);
                break;
            case 13:
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Socket Error!", L"Benachrichtigung", MB_ICONERROR);
                break;
            }
            
        }
        break;
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
        if (hWndEdit == (HWND)lParam) {
            HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
            SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(211, 211, 211));
            //SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(211, 211, 211)); // For diffrent color of latters
            SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(211, 211, 211));
            return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        TextOut(hdc, 20, 20, L"Gewünschte Taster Zyklen Eingeben", strlen("Gewünschte Taster Zyklen Eingeben"));
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    HWND hWnd;
    HWND hButton;
    WNDCLASS wc;
    MSG msg;

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MessageHandler;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WINAPITest";

    assert(RegisterClass(&wc));

    hWnd = CreateWindow(L"WINAPITest", L"WinAPI Tutorial", WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 300, 200, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    hButton = CreateWindow(L"button", L"OK", WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD, 40, 100, 200, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)10, hInstance, 0);
    hWndEdit = CreateWindow(L"edit", NULL, WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE, 40, 48, 200, 50, hWnd, 0, 0, 0);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (true) {
        BOOL result = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
        if (result > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One issue I can spot - Your `WM_PAINT` case statement is invoking BeginPaint, but not invoking EndPaint. Then without a break statement, it falls through to DefWindowProc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two bugs:

As I called out in the comments, you are forgetting to invoke EndPaint and have a missing break statement.  Fixing that and cleaning up your code so you don't have to duplicate the string:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    const wchar_t* message = L"Gewünschte Taster Zyklen Eingeben";
    TextOut(hdc, 20, 20, message, wcslen(message));
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    return 0;  // THIS LINE ADDED
```

Bug #2 is that you are forgetting to invoke RegisterClass on your WNDCLASSEX structure. Also, it's usually a good idea to default initialize that struct (to zeros) in case you missed a field or wanted to skip it.

```
wc = {}; // zero-init   THIS LINE ADDED
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = MessageHandler;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = L"WINAPITest";

RegisterClass(&wc);  // THIS LINE ADDED
```

After I removed the TCP Client stuff, I got your program to somewhat work:

[image]

And for some style points, I cleaned up this:

```
while (true) {
    BOOL result = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
    if (result > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

To simply be this:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
return 0;
```